# Workflow is not working as expected

Tags: apex, community, workflow, validation

Hey i got a scenario like i have a custom field called Demo date in custom object.

So i got a requirement like user had to select date only once.If they try to modify they will an error.

So for this requirement i create a check box(Demo_date_validation__c) with default FALSE and wrote validation rule like.

```
AND( ISCHANGED( Demo_Scheduled__c ), Demo_date_validation__c = true )
```

And i create a workflow like

```
ISCHANGED( Demo_Scheduled__c )
```

And do a field update for Demo_date_validation__c = true.

While i try to create any opportunity the workflow is not working.when i edit the corresponding opportunity the workflow works like a charm.

Means it working from 2nd time.

I create another workflow with same field update like above.

Demo Scheduled not equal to null

It's working fine now.If we combine both workflows nothing is happening. can anyone suggest me.

Please can you tell me where i had done the mistake

Comment: As per your requirement the user can select date only once , technically when they create a record validation should not fire and that is happening as expected right? A little confused on what you want exactly

Comment: @Rao i had change my question can you look on that once now.

Comment: It looks like you want to set `Demo_date_validation__c` to true also when `Demo_Scheduled__c` was populated. Is this true? You can modify workflow formula to `OR( ISCHANGED( Demo_Scheduled__c ), AND( ISNEW(), NOT( ISBLANK( Demo_Scheduled__c ))))`

Comment: It Works like charm buddy thank's you save a lot of time..@Oleksiy